# Remove 'Black Bar' (UI Debugger) From WPF Window

Tags: c#, wpf

So whenever I try and run any WPF application in Visual Studio 2015, this black box thingy appears:

[image]

Here's what the icons say:

[image]
[image]
[image]

How do I get rid of it?
Thanks.

Comment: @GrantWinney added details

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking at the [UI Debugger](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2015/02/24/introducing-the-ui-debugging-tools-for-xaml/), which lets you do similar things as [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/), which is also an excellent tool that has saved me a lot of trouble in the past.

That being said, you have two options to disable it:

1. Detach the debugger, or run without debugging
2. See the [answers in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36618494/disable-visual-studio-2015-extra-debug-option)

Comment: Not really sure why the downvote

Comment: even tho this is quite some time ago. I think the answer was downvoted because you answered the question while you could have marked this question as duplicate and then paste your link to the answer in a comment or something.