# How I can switch off additonal menu in Win2D Windows 10 Universal App

Tags: c#, windows, universal, win2d

I just have simple question, where how to switch off this menu?
[LINK to pirntscreen](http://www93.zippyshare.com/v/mJT8OZNB/file.html) 
I disable already frame counter in:

```
#if DEBUG
if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
{
    //this.DebugSettings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;
}
#endif
```

in method :

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This UI is coming from XAML, not Win2D.

Information about how to disable it: [Disable Visual Studio 2015 extra debug option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36618494/disable-visual-studio-2015-extra-debug-option)