# Removing weird black panel or toolbar displaying on wpf window

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, window

I want to get rid of this visual studio generated black something displaying in my WPF window. I don't even know what is it, so I cannot find anything about that in the Internet.

[image: I want to get rid of that]

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Visual studio doesn't generate anything unless you ask it to. Maybe you have some lingering/unwanted code which you forgot to remove.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL it's part of every WPF project that's created via Visual Studio, it's not custom code

Comment: Could you show some of your xaml code?

Comment: @JayGould Good catch!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This will solve your issue:

`Tools –> Options –> Debugging –> General –> Enable UI Debugging Tools for XAML`

Taken from: [Disable Visual Studio 2015 extra debug option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36618494/disable-visual-studio-2015-extra-debug-option)

Comment: You should have voted to close the question as duplicate.

Comment: 3 years later this is still the first result in google. Do not close as duplicate.

Comment: For VS 2019, there exist a new option called HOT Reload (almost same path)
Disable instead