# Visual Studio 2015 how to disable the buttons shown in the picture when debugging?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I reinstalled Windows 10 on my computer and wanted to install Visual Studio 2015 Community again. Since then I have these buttons when debugging my code. How can I disable it completely?

[image: buttons]

Comment: what are these buttons names according to the tooltip when you mouseover them?

Comment: "Go to Live Visual Tree", "Enable Selection", "Display layout adorners", "Track focused element"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three possible ways to deactivate the XAML UI debugging tools in Visual Studio 2015.

Have a look at the answers here: [Disable Visual Studio 2015 extra debug option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36618494/disable-visual-studio-2015-extra-debug-option)