# Disable Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 extra debug option digit box

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp

When I start to debug my application in Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Version 14.0.x Update 3, and I open a *HelloWorld* UWP App dialog I get some extra debugging options in a black square in a left corner. See image blow:

[image]

I have tried this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36618494/disable-visual-studio-2015-extra-debug-option) but not any success.

Anyone have an idea how to remove this?

Comment: add a bounty to the original issue if you still need help and not ask the same again

Comment: @magicandre1981 - my question is different from your referred question I've already mentioned this one in my question

Comment: @RobCaplan-MSFT This the solution exactly i want