# LiveChart's CartesianChart Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, livecharts

I Have LiveCharts cartesian, when i execute my application some black icon display's in any charts as indicate in the picture

How can iI hide these icons?

[Image displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gf8Ao.png)

Answer (score 0):

These only appear when the application is run in debug mode.

So you could run without debugging.

or you could try this

[Disable Visual Studio 2015 extra debug option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36618494/disable-visual-studio-2015-extra-debug-option)

Comment: thanx brother it works :) :)