# Hide the black bar on Visual Studio 2022 (Go to live visual tree etc.)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

There's a black bar on top of a newly created WPF app, including buttons such as `Go to live visual tree`. How do I get rid of it?

There used to be an option under Tools -> debugging called "Show runtime tools in application". It's not there anymore.

[image]

So how do I hide it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65540113/1043380

Comment: @gunr2171 You can turn that into an answer.

Comment: I'd rather turn it into a duplicate.

Comment: Doesn't make sense as a duplicate as the tags, name and version are diffrent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's moved in VS2022 to Tools -> Debugging here:

[image]